# Anaconda directory in $PATH - origin obscure

Tags: linux, path, ubuntu-16.04, anaconda, .bash-profile

Running Ubuntu 16.04, Cuda 8.0, OpenMPI4

I have the anaconda directory showing up in my $PATH although is not supposed to be there.

```
echo $PATH | grep anaconda

/opts/relion3/:/opts/pymol/:/opts/phenix-1.14-3260/build/bin:/opts/openmpi4/bin:/opts/ccp4/ccp4-7.0/etc:/opts/ccp4/ccp4-7.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/opts/cmake-3.13.4-Linux-x86_64/bin:/opts/UCSF/Chimera64-1.12rc/bin:/opt/anaconda/bin/:/home/schulzei/bin:/home/schulzei/.local/bin:/afs/desy.de/common/passwd:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/home/schulzei/opt/anaconda/bin:/opts/end.rapid/:/opts/nxds/:/opts/xds/
```

This causes a number of problems, with respect to MPI libraries etc. I would like to get rid of anaconda from my $PATH.

However, it is NOT sourced / exported in either

.bashrc

.zshrc

.condarc

.profile

/etc/profile

/etc/environment

I have also tried actively removing it by placing

```
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:\/opt\/anaconda\/bin$//')
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:\/opts\/anaconda\/bin$//')
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:\/home\/schulzei\/opt\/anaconda\/bin$//')
```

in my .bashrc.

Is there a way to identify how the anaconda directory gets into my $PATH ?

Thanks,

E

Comment: You haven't checked all possibilities. See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: Thanks - that was really helpful to have an overview. But still - none of those files point to anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the mystery. It was important to log out and log in again. Not just restart the shell.

Best,

E

"